# How to replace two strings as literals with sed?

Tags: sed

I want to replace `content: [],` with `content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],` using sed and I'm trying this command:

```
echo content: [], | sed -e s/content: \[\]/content: \['\.\/src\/\*\*\/\*\.\{js,jsx,ts,tsx}']/
```

But I get this error:

```
zsh: no matches found: [],
sed: 1: "s/content:
": unterminated substitute pattern
```

Ideally I want to treat the two sides in the sed command as literal strings but apparently no matter what, it treats different characters as regular expression parts.

Comment: `echo "content: []," | sed "s/content: \[\]/content: ['.\/src\/**\/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}']/"` seems to work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to wrap both the `echo` and `sed` command in quotes (`""`) so ZSH won't expand them:

```
echo 'content: [],' | sed -e "s/content: \[\]/content: \['\.\/src\/\*\*\/\*\.\{js,jsx,ts,tsx}']/"
```

```
content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
```